# Joining excel records based on column data

Tags: excel

I have 3 excel spreadsheets with the same columns and (supposedly) the same data. I need to line up all 3 documents and look for inconsistencies within the data. The data is server information at a data center and I would like the server location(row/cab) and Asset Tags to match horizontally for an easy view of differences between the 3 documents. If a document would be missing the server (No matching asset tag or location is empty) then I would want a blank line inserted in the other 2 documents showing that it is not present. Hopefully that all makes sense.

Here is the image of all 3 sheets put together. (ignore the colors)

[Excel Image http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/2937/unledcco.png](http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/2937/unledcco.png)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Would it be correct to view one of the spreadsheets as the master copy (i.e. every asset tag appears in that spreadsheet) and the other two spreadsheets contain some subset of the asset tags in the master copy? So, if every asset tag was listed in column C in the screenshot, then the lists of asset tags in columns H and M will contain some of the asset tags from column C but neither H nor M will contain any additional asset tags which aren't present in column C. Is this on the right lines?

Comment: Not exactly. C, H, and M could all contain tags not located in another asset tag column, my goal being to line up the asset tags that do match so I can verify the rest of the information is correct. It would also help to have it sorted by row/cab as the first column is

Comment: OK. So you would need to construct a master list of all asset tags (whether listed in one or more of C, H and M) and then line up the records from each spreadsheet against that master list to find where the gaps are

Comment: Hmm, So something like if asset tag does not equal other asset tag then create a row, and loop that through everything... I'll see what I can come up with.

Comment: I'm also debating setting up 3 tables in a SQL server and seeing if maybe it would be easier there. Thoughts?

Comment: You can use SQL within Excel using ADO (i.e. no separate SQL server required.) I'll try and work up an example over the weekend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an ADO based solution using Excel and VBA. If you need more info about using ADO with Excel/VBA then try http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

I'm going to assume that all three of your spreadsheets are in a single workbook and that they are named Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3. Obviously adjust the code as necessary.

To use ADO, go to the Visual Basic Editor (via the menus or via `Alt`-`F11`) and then via Tools > References (or its equivalent in later versions) add a reference to: "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library"

I'm using the provider and connection string for Excel 2003 and earlier because that's the version I have. For Excel 2007 and later, use these instead (replacing the filename of course):

`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0`

`Data Source=filename;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;`

(NB you'll often see "HDR=Yes" in connection strings but this is the default setting for Excel and thus can be omitted)

Firstly we'll create a master list of asset tags from the original three spreadsheets. Create a blank sheet and call it Sheet4 so that we have somewhere to put the list.

In a normal module, add the following then run it:

```
Sub master_list()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
End With

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "SELECT [Asset Tag] FROM [Sheet1$] UNION SELECT [Asset Tag] FROM [Sheet2$] UNION SELECT [Asset Tag] FROM [Sheet3$];", cn

With Worksheets("Sheet4")
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Master"
    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

The `UNION` operator in SQL only returns distinct records so this query has given us a complete list of the asset tags in all three spreadsheets with no duplicates. I've used "Master" as the column name to prevent any ambiguity later on

Now we need to combine the data from the three individual sheets with the master list. Create a new blank sheet and call that Sheet5. Now add and run the following:

```
Sub compare_sheets()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    .Open
End With

Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open "SELECT * FROM (([Sheet4$] LEFT JOIN [Sheet1$] ON [Sheet4$].[Master] = [Sheet1$].[Asset Tag]) " & _
    "LEFT JOIN [Sheet2$] ON [Sheet4$].[Master] = [Sheet2$].[Asset Tag]) " & _
    "LEFT JOIN [Sheet3$] ON [Sheet4$].[Master] = [Sheet3$].[Asset Tag];", cn

Dim fld As ADODB.Field
Dim i As Integer
i = 0
With Worksheets("Sheet5")
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        i = i + 1
        .Cells(1, i).Value = fld.Name
    Next fld

    .Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
End With

rs.Close
cn.Close

End Sub
```

That should hopefully give you the data from all three spreadsheets presented against a master list of asset tags. The column names will probably be a bit odd-looking (e.g. "Sheet1$.Asset Tag" etc) and all of the formatting will be lost but at least you can see which sheets are missing data

Comment: What's the correct formatting for the connection string? I keep getting Syntax errors/expect end statement.       .ConnectionString =  Data Source=C:\Users\hulc01\Desktop\FinalView.xlsm;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml

Comment: @Chris Hull - sorry, I lost a `;` off the end of the connection string. It should be: `Data Source=filename;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;`

Comment: I had to close that section within quotes to get it to work. Everything else looked to work PERFECTLY, just have to make it look pretty and give it to someone else now =D

Answer (score -2):

Using macros, you can do it.

```
Sub Insert_Rows_Loop()
  Dim CurrentSheet As Object
  ' Loop through all selected sheets.
  For Each CurrentSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
    ' Insert n rows depending on values
    //  **** 
    // Write your conditions 
    //  ****
    // Insert a row as below
    CurrentSheet.Range("b:b").EntireRow.Insert
    // Do other stuffs....
  Next CurrentSheet
End Sub
```