# Just want to display searched data into list box

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, listbox

I ran into a problem where I search for a bill number in list box via a text box. I find that data in list box. But the problem is every other record before that data is also being displayed to it. In the image....I searched for bill number 100

[image]

it searches it and display all the data until it reaches bill number 100. It doesn't display after that bill. Just wanted to remove/hide non-required data in list box when I search.

Code for the search command:-

```
Private Sub cmd_Search_Click()
    Dim h As Worksheet
  
    Set h = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales")
    Dim lr, i, bill, ex As Integer
    lr = h.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    bill = Me.txt_Bill_id.Value
    
    For i = 2 To lr
        ex = h.Cells(i, 3).Value
       
            If ex = bill Then
            With Me.lb_SaleList
                .ColumnCount = 10
                .ColumnHeads = True
                .ColumnWidths = "45,45,45,75,75,55,45,90,50,80"
                .RowSource = "Sales!A2:J" & i
         End With
        Else
            MsgBox "Bill Number not correct"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, you're just trying to [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter)?

Comment: Yeah! You can say that. Only the searched data should be displayed on list box!

Comment: Try taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872651/filtering-column-based-on-range-vba/11873370, noting you can have the range `"A:A"` be your table (determined dynamically, as a Table, or a fixed range).

Comment: I've got add function for this particular data on different form. So range ain't fixed.